# Selenium Click not working on IE11 using c#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, quality-assurance, ie11, .net

Local Machine: Dell Latitude (i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz 2.11 GHz) with 16.0 GB RAM
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro (64-bit) v1909
Display Scale and Layout: 100%

Running on Visual Studio 2017 (v 15.9.21)
.NET Framework (v 4.8.03752)
Selenium NuGet package Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver (v3.150.1) by jsakamoto

Internet Explorer 11, (v 11.836.18362.0) with Zoom = 100%

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();  
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;  
options.RequireWindowFocus = true;  
options.AddAdditionalCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);  
options.EnablePersistentHover = true;  
options.EnsureCleanSession = true;  
options.EnableNativeEvents = false;  
options.UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Accept;  
options.ElementScrollBehavior = InternetExplorerElementScrollBehavior.Top;  
options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;  
options.EnsureCleanSession = true;  
options.AddAdditionalCapability("IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION", true);  
options.AddAdditionalCapability("JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED", true);
```

Classic ASP page
Element is an input element of type="button"

I instantiate the element using a factory, and the element variable name is "btnsearch"
I then execute the following code and NONE of these approaches will trigger a Click event. Each approach *appears* to click the element, but the element doesn't seem to fire the click event through Selenium. If I physically click on the button, it fires the click event.

```
<code>
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(1119,3)"); // this is the coordinates of the element once scrolled into view  
IJavaScriptExecutor clicker = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
clicker.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", btnsearch);
driver.ExecuteJavaScript<object>("arguments[0].click();", btnsearch);  
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.MoveToElement(btnsearch).SendKeys(Keys.Enter).Build().Perform();  
btnsearch.Click();
</code>
```

I've even tried to add an event listener to send a keyup event (Enter key) and Selenium throws an exception "Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'"

HELP PLEASE!!! I have searched extensively for a way to make this happen and have experimented with multiple variations of the IE Options (on and off) along with different coded methods. Unfortunately, the developers that work on this legacy app are unlikely to make any substantive updates until this app becomes sunsetted. What other things can I try? I'd even take a complicated workaround just to make my automation work until the sunset actually occurs.

Comment: Actions act = new Actions(driver); act.MoveToElement(btnsearch).click()

Comment: clicker.ExecuteScript("$(arguments[0]).click();", btnsearch);

Comment: Try this two  and see if it's working ?

Comment: @PDHide The first suggestion did nothing, it behaves like all the other attempts. The second suggestion threw an exception "openqa.selenium.webdriverexception: error from javascript: access is denied." I don't have that much javascript experience, so I'm not sure where to start granting access. Thoughts?

Comment: @rsaparilla is the page fully loaded ? could you add a wait and check the button is clickable before executing the script

Comment: https://ibb.co/dLTgzDj    Open the dev tool goto console  $('csslocator').click(), use the css locator for the button inside  quotes  eg: `$('button#submit-button').click()` means element with tag button and id submitbutton . See if it triggers the click event. IF it does then try . `clicker.ExecuteScript("$('button#submit-button').click();");`

Comment: The link in my comment takes to a gif that shows how i did that

Comment: @PDHide I will give it a shot. My page object factory creates each element with an explicit wait, so it instantiates the button only when it satisfies the explicit condition. I use the XPath selector so I'll give it a shot with the CSS Selector and see what happens.

Comment: @PDHide The good news is that the console allowed me to fire the button click using the suggested method. The bad news is that when I tried it from my code, Selenium is somehow not authenticating correctly. It throws an exception "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Error from JavaScript: Access is denied."

Comment: Try dissabling protected mode in IE and run see whats happening

Comment: remove script related  security,

Comment: For me scripts works without issue with default IE settings, try setting all security settings to low. Compare with your local IE settings and organisations IE setting

Comment: Try running the script in other browser before all this , to see if its a IE related issue or not

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the JSE you don't need to scroll to the element (JS can interact with elements not in the `ViewPort`). You could just use the JSE to click the search button.

```
// declare JSE
// run JS to click the `button`
// (important) wait for the new page/element before proceeding
```

OR you can just use your JSE to run `Element.scrollTo()` and then do the normal Selenium Actions (which I would prefer since Selenium has helpers in their commands like click waits for page loads unlike JSE .click)

```
// declare JSE
// run JSE to scrollTo
// webDriver.click(myElement)
```